# get the maximum of multiple dataframes in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

i have a huge dataset of many column and I want to get the max of each cell in new df max_df

```
df1=data.frame(
          aa=c(12,13,14,15,16,17,16,17,19),
          bb=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,5,6,7))

df2=data.frame(
          aa=c(NA,12,12,13,14,12,17,14,15),
          bb=c(NA,2.5,3.5,2.5,3,4,5,6,7.5))

df3=data.frame(
          aa=c(13,14,15,16,15,14,10,20,21),
          bb=c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
```

desired output

```
max_df=data.frame(aa=C(NA,14,15,16,16,17,17,20,21),
                  bb=c(NA,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
```

**NOTE**
code has to give the max for all the columns available [ so we cant use aa and bb directly in our code]

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. If you have 3 DataFrames, you should have three rows in your result. Or, what are your grouping criteria?

Comment: well, there isn't any other column, it's just a numeric data frame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `pmax`:

```
as.data.frame(Map(pmax, df1, df2, df3))
#  aa bb
#1 NA NA
#2 14  3
#3 15  4
#4 16  5
#5 16  6
#6 17  7
#7 17  8
#8 20  9
#9 21 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar Base R to Roland's solution above, but using `Reduce()` to handle the cumulative nature of the problem:

```
Reduce(pmax, list(df1, df2, df3))
```